# How to coordinate 2 charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

Goal: Create two graps one of line type, another of type columnrange.
I use react-highcharts, highcharts-more, highchartsExporting. X axis in both cases is type:datetime. And use timestamp (ms).

```
let eventsChartOpts = {
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true,
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingBottom: 0,
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderRadius: 3,
      dataLabels: {
        align: 'left',
        enabled: true,
        inside: true,
        formatter: function() {
          if (!this.key)
            return null;
          return this.key;
        },
        padding: 5,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
          textShadow: 'none',
          whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
        },
        useHTML: true
      }
    }
  },
  series:events,
  tooltip: {
    enabled: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    visible: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: moment(dates[1]).unix()*1000,
    max: moment(dates[dates.length-1]).unix()*1000,
    minTickInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // one day
    opposite: true,
    showFirstLabel: false,
    showLastLabel: false,
    type:'datetime' 
  },
};
```

and

```
let config = {
  chart:{
    type: 'line',
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingBottom: 0,
    },
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    xAxis: {
      crosshair: {
        color: '#e3e3e3',
        snap: true
      },
      gridLineWidth: 1,
      labels: {
        align: 'center'
      },
      min: moment(dates[0]).unix()*1000,
      max: moment(dates[dates.length-1]).unix()*1000,
      minTickInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // one day
      showFirstLabel: false,
      showLastLabel: false,
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
      maxPadding: 0.1,
      reversed: false,
      visible: false
    },
    series:rates
};
```

But what i get:

[image]

X axes, don't match, although settings is the same. I don't understand why. I thought problem in padding, but no, i have equal padding. I need your help.

Comment: Could you recreate your problem in a working JSFiddle demo? I tried to do it using your code but I aligned both axes (yAxis in the first example and xAxis in the second example) without any problems. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/waevhm7d/.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer. I added my data, that what i got http://jsfiddle.net/uh6azab4/1/

Comment: And what we have on time 'week' http://jsfiddle.net/uh6azab4/2/

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Simply set `startOnTick` and `endOnTick` with false or true value in both axes. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/n7x7qgee/.